# Custom Live Agent Chat Window on an external website

Tags: liveagent

I want to know if it's possible to customize Live Agent Chat Window using visualforce, and it's to be deployed to an external website using the deployment code snippet.

At the current stage, I have deployed the code, and it's working fine using the default live agent chat window, but if I set it to my customized chat window, it give an error about refused to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Update.

Problem fixed, I just needs to set the public access method of the force.com site that is hosting the chat window to same origin and external domain.